# error when replacing multiple words in line using sed

Tags: sed, scripting

I'm using below script to replace a list of words in a file.

However I'm getting this error while executing the script:

```
can't read s/@@/AU/g: No such file or directory
```

Can  you please let me know the issue in script?

```
# source the properties:
. config.properties

######## Generating test data on runtime  ###############
echo "**************************************************************************"
echo "         Test Data Generation for Markets        ..                      *"
echo "**************************************************************************"
IFS="," read -ra items <<<"$markets"

for item in "${items[@]}"
do
    Country=`echo $item|tr [a-z] [A-Z]`
    date1=$(date --date="20 day ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    date2=$(date --date="400 day ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    epoch1=$(date --date="20 day ago" +%s)
    epoch2=$(date --date="40 day ago" +%s)

    cp Sample_testdata testdata_$UPPER_CASE
    sed -i "s/@@/${Country}/g"  -e "s/date-20/${date1}/g" -e "s/date-400/${date2}/g" -e "s/epoch_date-20/${epoch1}/g" -e "s/epoch_date-40/${epoch2}/g" testdata_$UPPER_CASE

    echo "test data generation completed for Market :: $Country"

done
```

Comment: where could be issue in sed command.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: + sed -i s/@@/AU/g -e 's/date-20/2017-02-04 04:09/g' -e 's/date-400/2016-01-21 04:09/g' -e s/epoch_date-20/1486206552/g -e s/epoch_date-40/1484478552/g testdata_
sed: can't read s/@@/AU/g: No such file or directory

Comment: @VishalPatial You can edit your question post, please do that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add the exact error message you get; ii) show us an example of your input file and iii) the output you are expecting from that input file.

Answer (score 4):

When using several `-e` bits with `sed`, make sure that *all* the parts are prefixed with `-e`, including the first one:

```
sed -e ... -e ... -e ... -e ...
```

and not

```
sed ... -e ... -e ... -e ...
```

Alternatively, you could use one (and only one) `sed` expression, in which case you can omit the `-e` and use `;` or newlines to separate the commands in that  one expression:

```
sed -i "s/@@/${Country}/g; s/date-20/${date1}/g; ..." file
```

Or

```
sed -i "
  s/@@/${Country}/g
  s/date-20/${date1}/g
  ..." file
```

Comment: @VishalPatial If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.